# How to check a condition on each element of each row with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For machine learning, I'm appliying Parzen Window algorithm.

I have an array (m,n). I would like to check on each row if any of the values is > 0.5 and if **each** of them is, then I would return 0, otherwise 1.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this without a loop thanks to numpy.

Comment: If all entries in one row are >0.5, isn't then the first requirement that at least one of them is anyways true? Or did you mean OR?

Comment: Can you please give a try yourself first? What is your best attempt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.all` with `axis=1` on a boolean array.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0.8, 0.9], [0.1, 0.6], [0.2, 0.3]])

print(np.all(arr>0.5, axis=1))
>> [True False False]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

# Value Initialization
a = np.array([0.75, 0.25, 0.50])
y_predict = np.zeros((1, a.shape[0]))

#If the value is greater than 0.5, the value is 1; otherwise 0
y_predict = (a > 0.5).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array (m,n). I would like to check on each row if any of the values is > 0.5

That will be stored in `b`:

```
import numpy as np
a =  # some np.array of shape (m,n)
b = np.any(a > 0.5, axis=1)
```

> and if each of them is, then I would return 0, otherwise 1.

I'm assuming you mean 'and if this is the case for all rows'. In this case:

```
c = 1 - 1 * np.all(b)
```

`c` contains your return value, either `0` or `1`.